# Why xargs doesn't see delimiters on MacOS?

Tags: macos, xargs

I'm doing this:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb" | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 -t echo X
```

I'm getting:

```
echo X a b
X a b
```

I'm expecting:

```
echo X a
X a
echo X b
X b
```

What am I doing wrong? It's MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xargs` normally passes *groups* of arguments to the specified command. As the man page says (with emphasis added):

> Any arguments specified on the command line are given to *utility* upon each invocation, followed by **some number** of the arguments read from the standard input of `xargs`.

`xargs` has several options to limit how many arguments are passed at a time. `-n`, which just sets a numeric limit, is all you need here:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb" | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 -n1 -t echo X
echo X a
X a
echo X b
X b
```